Auerbach's Lemma

(Auerbach's Lemma) Let $X$ be a finite-dimensional normed space with $\operatorname{dim}_{\mathbb{K}} X = n$. Then, there exists a set $\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\} \subset X$ and $\{f_1, \ldots, f_n\} \subset L(X; \mathbb{K})$ such that $|x_i| = |f_i| = 1$ and $f_i(x_j) = \delta_{ij}$.

Every proof of this result seems to involve somewhat complicated arguments with determinants. I don’t see why this isn’t immediate from the existence of a basis for $X$ with elements of norm $1$. If we simply define $f_i$ as usual for the dual basis, we can easily check linearity and that $|f_i| = 1$. This should be straightforward, as $X$ is finite-dimensional. So, what am I missing here?

How do you show that $|f_i|=1$ though?

For example, consider the 1-norm $\lVert (x,y)\rVert := \lvert x\rvert +\lvert y\rvert$, what happens if you take $X={(1,0), (\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})}$?

@Mark I thought about arguing in the following way: Take $x \in X$. Then, $|f_i(x)| = |\sum_{1 \leq j \leq n} \lambda_j f_i(x_j)| = |\lambda_i| \leq \max_n{|\lambda_1|, \ldots, |\lambda_n|} = |x|$. That is, $|f_i| \leq 1$. By taking $x := x_i$, we obtain $|f_i(x)| = 1$, so $|f_i| \geq 1$. I did fix the $\operatorname{max}$ norm. Could that be the issue? Is Auerbach's lemma about an arbitrary norm?

@huh To answer “Is Auerbach's lemma about an arbitrary norm?”, the norm on $X$ is a given data. That is, the norm of $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i x_i$ is determined by the rule how the norm on $X$ assigns $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i x_i$ to some real number, not necessarily $\max |\lambda_i|$.

@Asigan That makes sense. I got it now.
